# Form capaz de direcionar pra duas urls no DJANGO

Tags: python, django

Bom estou elaborando um CRUD simples e gostaria de utilizar uma única página html, mas me deparei com um problema o form para criar seria o mesmo para editar, a princípio acredito que seriam necessários dois button´s um que acionaria a url 'adicionar' e outro para a url 'editar'

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'homePessoa' %}">Pessoa</a></li>
</ul>
<form action="{% url 'adicionarPessoa' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nomeCompleto">
    <input type="date" name="dataNascimento">
    <button type="submit">Incluir</button>
    <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
</form>
{% for i in pessoas %}
    <p>{{ i.id }} - {{ i.nome_completo }} - {{ i.data_nascimento }} / <a href="{% url 'editarPessoa' i.id %}">Editar</a> / <a href="{% url 'excluirPessoa' i.id %}">Excluir</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

Mas como linkar esses dois buttons com suas respectivas url´s

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a tag `<a>` para direcionar cada botão para uma URL diferente:

```
<a href="url_incluir/">
    <button type="button">Incluir</button>
</a>
<a href="url_salvar/">    
    <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
</a>
```